# Get time in Microseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

Is there any function or logic in javascript by which I can get my time in microseconds? I'm trying to get time as`var s = new Date();` here the minimum unit I get is Milliseconds, but how can I get this time in microseconds?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857272/javascript-) it may helpfull for you

Comment: Check this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233927/microsecond-timing-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new "High Resolution Time"
http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/

Example and demo here: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-html5-apis-worth-looking/

Answer (score 1):

use package microtime
To install : npm install microtime

```
var us = require('microtime');
var us_time = us.now();
```

[To know more about microtime check this link](https://github.com/wadey/node-microtime)

Comment: If you intend to use this to get the system date and time in milliseconds rather than using this for timing, this is the better answer.